# Difference between simple cat and redirecting the to a variable

Tags: shell-script, permissions, kali-linux, cat

I have written the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Power Details"
fall='/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1'
full=cat $fall/energy_full
echo 'printing here'
echo $full
```

It is showing the following error:

```
./power.sh: line 4: /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full: Permission denied
```

The file I am accessing has read permissions to all. Also, while I am simply printing the output of the file, like (editing line 4 of the code):

```
cat $path/energy_full
```

It shows no error. Why is this so? How are `cat filename` v/s `var1 = cat filename` different? What should I do to resolve the issue, without changing read-write-execute permissions of the file I want to access?
**NOTE: I am running Kali Linux as a root user**

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html

Comment: This is probably because read privilege is different from execute privilege, and even the root user needs execute privilege to execute. To fix do: `chmod a+x ./power.sh`. Do `man chmod` for more information on how privileges work.

Comment: Try enable the "BASIC debugger", which is: add `set -x` in line 2 of the script. This will echo the commands to the console while executing them.

Comment: @John I thought of the same thing, regarding privileges. But the thing that confused me is how simple cat command is working while redirecting the output a variable not. What makes the two commands different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the wrong syntax to assign the output of a command to a variable.

To answer your question as asked, the difference between `cat filename` and `var=cat filename` is that in the first case you are executing the command `cat` on `filename`.  In the second, you are executing the command `filename` while setting the value of `var` to `cat`.  However, `filename` is not an executable command, so you are getting a permission error.

Since you actually want to assign the output of the `cat` command to a variable, you need to do it like this:

```
var=$(cat filename)
```

Comment: And quote those variables when you use them, `full=$(cat "$fall/energy_full")`

Comment: BTW, the command `var1 = cat filename` (given in the discussion) would do something still different -- it would try to run `var` as a command, with the parameters "=", "cat", and "filename". In the shell *spaces matter* so `x=y` and `x = y` do totally different things. Also, expanding @roaima's comment, you should also use double-quotes when `echo`ing the result (`echo "$full"`, not `echo $full`).